# Adjust predefined glossary style "longheaderborder" of package glossaries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossary

I tried to define a new glossary style based on the defined style "longheaderborder". It works well except that the bottom line of the longtable is missing. What should i do in my code to fix this issue? The following is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% define a new glossary style for acronyms
\newglossarystyle{acronym-longheaderborder}{%
    \setglossarystyle{longheaderborder}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{|p{\dimexpr .2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr .8\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}%
    {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Häufig benutzte Abkürzungen}\\
        \hline
        Bezeichnung & Beschreibung\\
        \hline
    }
}

% acronym example
\newacronym[description={Kompensierter linearer Verktordipol (Englisch: Compensated Linear Vector Dipole)}]{CLVD}{CLVD}{kompensierte lineare Vektordipol}

\makenoidxglossaries

% document
\begin{document}
    
\printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=acronym-longheaderborder]
\newpage
\gls{CLVD}

\end{document}
```

As you can find i get the result like this:
[image]

And besides, if i replace \printnoidxglossary and \makenoidxglossaries with \printglossary and \makeglossaries, it will produce no glossary at all. What causes this?